Is there a more concise definition for the 3 states of equilibrium?
I've read the following definition:

The centre of gravity of an object is the point through which the weight of the object acts. It can be considered as the point at which all the mass of an object appears to be concentrated.
For a uniform body (a body with equal density throughout), the centre of gravity is at the geometric centre. For example, the centre of gravity of a uniform rod is in the middle of the it.
A body will be in equilibrium when the resultant force and the resultant moment acting on it are both zero. Equilibrium can be either stable, unstable, or neutral.
In stable equilibrium, if a body is slightly displaced, it will tend to return to its original position. This happens when the centre of gravity is below the point of support.
In unstable equilibrium, if a body is slightly displaced, it will move further from its original position. This occurs when the centre of gravity is above the point of support.
In neutral equilibrium, a body stays where it is when slightly displaced. This happens when the centre of gravity is at the same level as the point of support.

But now look at these images from Wikipedia below which clearly show that the COG of the ball is above the point of support for stable and neutral equilibrium. So is the definition I stated at the beginning of my question incorrect? If yes, is there a more concise definition?
[Stable
[ Unstable
[ Neutral

How much more concise are you looking to get?  One sentence per definition (plus an example) is pretty good.  There are deeper definitions that let you put equations to them, but you still end up with 2 equations plus a "if neither of these apply" case.  And the equations are much harder than those words.

$\dots$ and metastable?

The definition I posted cannot be correct because the COG of the ball is not below the point of support for stable state, nor at the same level for neutral state. Yet in this video by Julius Sumner Miller he states the same definition as in my post . Look from 9:00 - 10:18. There seems to be contradiction in the definition versus the example images I posted above from Wikipedia.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrtZTlUHKr0

I would say that in each of your bold definitions, delete the second sentence and you have the real definition.

Many thanks for your reply.

You wont find much more concise than that.  As RC_23 points out in their answer, you could strip the example out of the bolded sentences to make it shorter, but that's about it.
The limiting factor is that these are rather informal concepts.  There's not complete agreement on these lines.  I'm assuming this is from a book or a website that uses these terms, and did you a good service by defining them beforehand.  There's also terms like "metastable" that show up from time to time. (this word also has different meanings in math and science)
More formally, we often talk about what kind of stability or instability we are working with.  For example, we may talk of stability in the form of a particle at rest (like these examples), or we may talk about stability of an orbit where an object is in motion (in its phase space), but if you perturb it, it works its way back to that same motion.  We also have very specific definitions like Lyapunov Stability which is a specific measure of asymptotic stability.
There are actually many criterion to define stability.  In the formal world, we do have to be aware of which defintion.  There are also multiple definitions of unstable (one definition in mathematics deals with the inverse of the function being stable).  So there's lots of detail that goes into it.  You don't need to get into this level of detail, but I point it out because it shows that it will be hard to get a one-size-fits-all concise definition.  When you get further into your physics career (should you choose to do so), we want to add more detail, not take detail away.
The definitions you were given are good definitions.  They do a good job of covering the content.  Wikipedia has a page on stability in classical mechanics which lines up exactly with the definitions you were given.  An entire Wikipedia page doesn't qualify as "more concise" than 3 sentences, but it may be useful for you.  You may be able to use the content on that page to refine those sentences into the concise content you need for your purposes.

The "point if support" should not be part of the definitions. My guess is that this part comes from a specific example, maybe with a mass on a rigid rod tied to a hinge point, which then is "the point of support".
In general, the definition of stability vs instability for equilibria is whether infinitesimal deviations from equilibrium will grow larger or smaller. Mathematically, for a function of one variable as an example, we would say something like: if $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for values $x=x_0\pm dx$ in the vicinity of $x_0$, then $x_0$ constitutes a local equilibrium point.

Many thanks . It's just that I found a video by "Julius Sumner Miller: Lesson 1 - The Idea of the Center of Gravity"  that said the same thing about 'point of support. Look at 09:00-10:18.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrtZTlUHKr0

@Dubious Yes, Mr. Miller is precisely talking about a specific example in which there is a point of support. He is not saying that there always is a point of support.

Steeven -  But for the images from Wikipedia , isn't there a point of support for the ball in the stable and neutral examples?  But the COG of the ball is above the point of support , not below it or at the same level (ie. for neutral).
